# Rx disposable not being created on time in unit tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, rx-java

I'm having trouble with testing the manual manipulation of disposables inside my class being tested. I have a `itemsProcessed` map that keeps track of the different disposables that are created, the reason is that some disposables I need to be able to dispose on demand, and others I just need to know they exist.

My class runs fine and everything works as expected, but in my tests, I noticed that the disposables that I make aren't being inserted into my map until what would be the async code is already completed.

I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the fact that I'm using

```
RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
```

Here are the relevant methods I'm testing, the `myRepo.processItem()` call is on a background thread

```
    private fun processItem(item: Item) {
        itemsProcessed[item] = myRepo.processItem(item)
                .doOnComplete {
                    safelyDelete(item)
                    itemsProcessed.remove(item)
                }
                .doOnError {
                    itemsProcessed.remove(item)
                }
                .subscribe({}, {})
    }

    private fun cleanOldItems() {
        itemList.forEach {
                if (!itemsProcessed[item].exist())
                        safelyDelete(it)
                }
    }
```

myRepo has a processor called `itemProcessor` which calls the method above, my test is as follows

```
    @Test
    fun doNotDeleteItemsBeingProcessed() {
        `when`(itemProcessor.processItem(any()))
                .thenAnswer {
                    //from my understanding of disposables, the disposable should have been made in my real class and should have been inserted into the map at this point
                    trigger cleanOldItems
                    Completable.timer(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                }

        repo.triggerProcessItems()

        Assert.assertTrue(itemList.contains(item))
    }
```

It seems like when I run the test, `itemsProcessed` map in my class is empty until the last assert line in my test is reached. When I added in `doOnSubscribe`, I noticed that `doOnSubscribe` was also called at the very end, what's causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

What does `trigger cleanOldItems` do? Assuming this is a synchronous call, then it'll call your cleaning function before it returns any disposable to store in your map. Instead, you should have

```
@Test
    fun doNotDeleteItemsBeingProcessed() {
        `when`(itemProcessor.processItem(any()))
                .thenAnswer {
                    //from my understanding of disposables, the disposable should have been made in my real class and should have been inserted into the map at this point
                    Completable.timer(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                }

        repo.triggerProcessItems()
        repo.triggerCleanOldItems()

        Assert.assertTrue(itemList.contains(item))
    }
```

Also bear in mind that `Completable.timer` call uses computation scheduler internally, so unless you explicitly provide a scheduler to it (as in `Completable.timer(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.trampoline()`) or override setComputationSchedulerHandler your subscription will be triggered on a different thread.